# What is different between ACID and Non-ACID SQL?

Tags: sql, acid

i am a student can you help me? what is different between ACID and Non-ACID SQL?? thank you..!

Comment: Have you tried Googling it? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID

Answer (score 1):

ACID is more related to the characteristics of the database you are using, and more specifically whether or not that database fully supports transactions than how well it supports SQL.  For instance, in the MySQL database, the SQL used to access data will largely be the same regardless of whether you use the myisam or innodb engines for your tables, but whereas innodb supports transactions myisam does not.

And without going too far down the rabbit hole, a transaction refers to capability of certain databases to group a series of SQL commands together and treat them as an all or nothing or "Atomic" act.  (Hence the "A" in ACID.)  For instance, in MySQL using the innodb engine the following group of statements represent a transaction:

```
start transaction;
insert into foo (data) values (1);
insert into foo (data) values (2);
commit;
```

So from the perspective of other users accessing they database they would either see neither of the new rows in foo or both, depending on whether or not the transaction had committed yet.  There would never be a situation where they would see only the first row or only the second.